# How to retrieve multiple blob images from database

Tags: java, image, hibernate, spring-mvc, jstl

Hi i am using Spring mvc and hibernate. I want to retrieve multiple blob images from database and want to display in jsp. I tried a lot but did not get fruitful answer. If anyone gives link or sample code then it would be great for me.

Comment: if I may, you should save the images separately and store their path in DB. That way, if your DB gets corrupted, images are safe , and if images are corrupt, DB is safe. + You have faster response time.

Comment: as per project requirement i am saving this as BLOB and want to display it in jsp. But did not get how to do this.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using MySql

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using spring you could also have a look at spring data and the data repositories (http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories). 
There are a lot examples out there how it should look in action :) 
If you use the newest Version you can stream the results. With that you can load the images async if you have performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using server side this code it's works for me

**Spring Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/getImages", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Product> getStateList(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {
        List<Product> image = imageService.getImageList();
        List<Product> imageList= new ArrayList<Product>();
        for (Product m : new ArrayList<Product>(image)) {
            String base64Encoded = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(m.getImage());
            Product imagepath = new Product();
            imagepath.setImagePath(base64Encoded);
            imagepath.setItemName(m.getItemName());
            imageList.add(imagepath);
        } 
        return imageList;
    }
```

DAO

```
public List<Product> getImageList() {
        String getImageQuery = "FROM Product";
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(getImageQuery);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Product> imgList = query.list();
        return imgList;
    }
```

**Model Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="imageUpload")
public class ImageUpload {

    @Id
    @Column(name="eloraId")
    private int eloraId;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="ownerName")
    private String ownerName;

    @Column(name="registeredId",columnDefinition="mediumblob")
    private byte[] registeredId;

    @Column(name="hospPanCard")
    private String hospPanCard;

    @Column(name="hospRegCert",columnDefinition="mediumblob")
    private byte[] hospRegCert;

    @Column(name="ownerPanCard",columnDefinition="mediumblob")
    private byte[] ownerPanCard;

    @Column(name="ownerselfDec",columnDefinition="mediumblob")
    private byte[] ownerselfDec;

    @Column(name="ownerAddProof",columnDefinition="mediumblob")
    private byte[] ownerAddProof;

    @Transient
    private String statusMessage;
}
```

Comment: are you storing blob images in ur database? And how will you display this image in jsp page?

Comment: yes blob images only storing in database.debug that code are you getting images in  imageList return type

Comment: hope it works..and what about displaying image in jsp page?

Comment: <img src="{image.imageId}"/>
 like this

Comment: can you please upload your model class?

Comment: ya sure check it

Comment: no its not working..i tried but did not get proper result

Comment: is images are saving or not in db

Comment: image is saving but I'm not getting how to convert blob to image file.

Comment: Use base64Encoded to convert blob to string and pass that string to response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146321/discussion-between-arnab-layek-and-umapathi).

Comment: I can fetch image but now i am getting another problem. In MySql i can see the image name and byte file. But did not see the image file. Any idea why i can't see image file in database?

Comment: no you can't see images on mysql database.images are saving string type. if you want to see images saved or not in database use mysql workbench. in workbench you can see only data type.

Comment: yes i am using mysql workbench..but still i can see the binary data and image name.

Comment: even when i fetch the image that time it comes blank.

Comment: @arnablayek ok. still facing same issue?

Comment: no the issue is fixed..Thanks for your comment. But i used Base64 to convert blob image to jpeg/png image.